# Prolog - Array of arrays, returning entries where array length is greater than one

Tags: prolog

I am very new to logical programming.

The purpose of this program is to return a list of all sibling groups. I am currently organizing parent/child groups like so:

```
/* Where Banana is the parent */
child_of(Apple, Banana).
child_of(Grape, Banana).
child_of(Pear, Banana).
child_of(Apricot, Pear).

display_siblings(X) :-
    findall(Siblings,
           bagof(
                C,
                child_of(_, C), Siblings), 
                X).
```

This not only returns all sibling groups, but seems to return all family groups in which only one child is available.

For example:

```
[[Apple, Grape, Pear], [Apricot]]
```

My first idea was to use this predicate:

```
not_just_one([X,Y]]) :-
    length(X, len),
    len \= 1,
    not_just_one(Y).
```

Which gives me the following error: `Illegal start of term`

How can I change `display_siblings` to only allow sibling pairs in which more than one child exists?

Comment: Substitute `]]` by `] and `len` by `Len`

Comment: These are really "lists" not "arrays" in particular because they cannot be accessed efficiently by index (although there is `nth0/3` which walks down the list N steps to unifiy with element N)

Comment: Please edit this questions. Using variables instead of atoms is confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

My predicate ended up looking like this:

```
yokatta(C,Siblings) :-
    bagof(C, child_of(_, C), Siblings),
    length(Siblings, X),
    X > 1.

display_siblings(Ss) :-
    findall(Siblings, yokatta(C,Siblings), Ss).
```

The reason this works is because it abstracts each list and then isolates the results to only results with a length score greater than 1.

Comment: Replace `length(Siblings, X), X > 1` by `Siblings = [_,_|_]` which is better placed directly after the head. Also, rather use `setof/3` in stead.

Comment: Doesn't that give you all sets of co-parents?